# Neural Turing Machine - how the shifting works?

Tags: neural-network

I am reading the paper on [Neural Turing Machine, page 9,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.5401.pdf) and got stuck on just 1 pesky point.

I can't understand how the shift is done:

> Each head emits a shift weighting $\vec{s_t}$ that defines a normalized distribution over the allowed integer shifts **(Authors mean entries in s will add up to 1)**. For example, if shifts between -1 and 1 are allowed, $\vec{s_t}$ has three elements corresponding to the degreee to which shifts of -1, 0 and 1 are performed.
>
> If we index the $N$ memory locations from 0 to $N-1$, the rotation applied to $\vec{w_t^g}$ by $\vec{s_t}$ can be expressed as the following circular convolution:
>
> $$w_{new}(i) \leftarrow \sum_{j=0}^{N-1}w^g_t(j)s_t(i-j)$$
>
> where all index arithmetic is computed modulo $N$.

The authors use notation $w_t(i)$ to signify i'th element in the vector.

I cannot understand how $s_t$ is applied to the $w^g_t$ and what makes it possible to actually perform shift, say by +1

---

For example, assume we are working on the the i'th element that is at index 3 and $w^g_t$ has 5 entries.

Like in the paper, let's allow $s$ to be able to perform a shift of -1, 0 or 1. Thus, $s$ has 3 dimensions. Now, I want to shift every element in $w$ by +1 forward.

I have a feeling I will get out of bounds error, and modulo won't help too much. We can unfold this computation for the 3rd element:

```
w[3] = wg[0]*s[(3-0)%5] + wg[1]*s[(3-1)%5] + wg[2]*s[(3-2)%5] + wg[3]*s[(3-3)%5] + wg[4]*s[(3-4)%5]
```

when simplified this means:

```
w[3] = wg[0]*s[3] + wg[0]*s[2] + wg[0]*s[1] + wg[0]*s[0] + wg[0]*s[4]
```

As you can see, I got s[3] at the start and s[4] at the end. ...But we've just agreed **s** will only have 3 entries {-1, 0, 1} and this means out of bounds error.

And, I can't really understand how what we've done would "shift" the entire $w^g$ into $w_{new}$ once we do it for all 5 entries (we've done the above just for 3rd entry). Can someone give me the intuition for it as well?

Comment: Your problem is not about this paper in particular, so try reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution or any DSP text book.

Comment: My concerns is mostly the W(j)S(i-j) part, where it seems we will get out of bounds, if W is 10-dimensional, and S is only 3-dimensional. For example if $i=0$ and $j=1$ we will have to wrap around using modulo 10, but will end up at index that's way larger than dimension of S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it makes sense if we don't think about the formula

Look at the bottom half of the following slide, taken from [Page 20, "Neural Turing Machine" side-presentation by Kiho Suh; June 19, 2017](https://www.slideshare.net/KihoSuh/neural-turing-machine-77087607)

[image]